# Playing music in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play music through an app I made through Android Studio. I know how to play an audio file if I just create a *raw folder* under `res` and add an audio file to that specific folder.

I would like to have it **directly call the audio file from my computer**.

I tried this:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("[my ip address: port 8080 @ where the file is at"));
```

Is it even possible to do this? Anything will help. I will continue looking while I await help. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean streaming from streaming server program (such as VLC) running on your computer, or accessing a file share/network folder/whatever on your computer from the phone, or something else?

Comment: So like accessing a folder on my desktop that isn't the direct link to the share folder. I'm using the emulator multi-emu. I know I can put a file in the shared sounds folder. But don't want to do it that way.

Comment: @hyde sorry there is what was missing

Comment: Okay so I realized that I actually needed to use a tomcat server and place the audio file within it and then make a http call to it to pull it.